# Manually set date & time to the future

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, clock

I'm trying to manually set date & time on my HTC/Galaxy Note 3 device. I am correctly able to set the date upto 30th July, but when I set date to 30th August 2016, the clock reverts back to current date & time.

Is there a maximum limit to set future date & time?

Comment: check if you've ticked auto time and date update

Comment: I have disabled auto time and date update. Then I manually changed the date to 30 Aug 2016 , but then it automatically reverted to current time . I tried the same with 30th July 2016 and that worked successfully

Comment: Most likely your device's warranty ends on August 1st #D Honestly: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need to set a future date?

Comment: Need to do e a future dated app testing , hence setting the clock for testing the application

Comment: I could succesfully set 30th Aug 2016 on LG G2 now.

Comment: Have you checked if there's 3rd-party app that may monitor and correct the date & time? Also, try with no internet connection. By default, I don't think there's a limitation to choose date, because Android doesn't know today's date without external assistance (e.g. time server sync).

Answer (score 1):

This is due to an issue in Google Play Services, and it doesn't seem like Google is interested in fixing this bug. 
Star this bug and make your voice heard : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36650